# Angular Type 'Observable<Message[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Message[]>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Noob to Angular2. I am following the tutorial for a whatsapp clone and have come across this error.

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable' is not a class derived from 'Observable'.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Chat, Message } from "api/models/chatsModel";
import { Messages } from "../../../api/collections/chatsCollection";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

/*
  Generated class for the Messages page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-messages',
  templateUrl: 'messages.html'
})
export class MessagesPage implements OnInit {

    selectedChat: Chat;
    title: string;
    picture: string;
    messages: Observable<Message[]>;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    this.selectedChat = <Chat>navParams.get('chat');
    this.title = this.selectedChat.title;
    this.picture = this.selectedChat.picture;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let isEven = false;

    this.messages = Messages.find({chatId: this.selectedChat._id},
        { sort: {createdAt: 1} }
        ).map((messages: Message[]) => {
            messages.forEach((message: Message) => {
                message.ownership = isEven ? 'mine' : 'other';
                isEven = !isEven;
            });
            return messages;
        });
  }

}
```

I understand that `this.messages` is not accepting the code following it because it is a different type than expected, but being that I am so new I'm not so sure on how to alter it to make it accept it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does `"../../../api/collections/chatsCollection"` refer to another project? With another `node_modules` directory? If so, that's the problem, as the two `rxjs` packages will not be seen as the same - hence the type error. It's not enough for packages to share the same name; if they reside in different locations on disk, they are different.

Comment: @cartant within my root directory I have an api folder that contains it's own nodes_modules, that folder is dedicated to the meteor backend. I am following this tutorial http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ . I know later on in the tutorial it needs me to import meteor-observable from rxjs located in the api/node_modules/rxjs.  I will follow the rest of the tutorial to see if it works out which should confirm what you are saying I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Observable and Message are both imported from same place and both are classes or interfaces not a mixture

Comment: How can Observable and Message be from the same place? I'm a bit confused on that.

Comment: Make sure if your code refers to message that all references to message refer to the same message class and not a different one or not a message interface